# making blueprint css working in IE 6 and IE 7

Tags: blueprint-css

I am using Blue print CSS and it works fine in Firefox...but when I look at it in IE, even with the  for IE lt IE8, it still doesn't seem to be working right in terms of spacing and alignment.

Any suggestions on what I can do to make it look proper?

Comment: Check if the path to the `.css` is correct or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you including the ie.css file?  Below the regular blueprint css files, include the `ie.css` file, using the notation that only IE will parse:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../blueprint/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../blueprint/print.css" type="text/css" media="print"> 
<!--[if lt IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="../../blueprint/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"><![endif]-->
```

Make sure that all the URLs to the CSS files are correct and are working on your site also.

Comment: I second this answer. They  intentionally put all of the IE hacks in a separate file to keep the code neat. 

IMO, it's great to have it separate in the unoptimized src/ version, but who isn't at least trying to support IE? I'm not sure why it has to be separate.

Comment: How can I check, my code does show teh IE hack and the other blueprint files are coming through properly.  It for the most part, appears right in IE, *except* for the alignment of the <legend> text and the lines in the <fieldset>

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you use a doctype.  If you do not it will render in quirks mode.  I had the same problem and correcting the doctype worked.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
```

That should go at the top of the document

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late, but hopefully it'll help someone who googles it.

A big gotcha when using blueprint here is to ensure that your container div has a *class* of container, not id:

```
<div class="container"> ... </div>
```

Not

```
<div id="container"> ... </div>
```

It's caught me out a few times before.